# Converting List to JSON Array in Spring with a parent?

Tags: json, spring, rest

I have a list of objects Request entity class which I am trying to return as a JSON array. I am writing the below code.

```
ResponseEntity<List<Request>> response;
List<Request> requestList= new ArrayList<Request>();
//populating requestList 
response=new ResponseEntity<List<Request>>(requestList,HttpStatus.OK);
return response;
```

I am getting the below JSON

```
[
  {"requestId":"1","description":"This is a sample","status_id":"1"},
  {"requestId":"2","description":"This is a sample","status_id":"1"}
]
```

I want to have a parent like

```
{"requests": [
      {"requestId":"1","description":"This is a sample","status_id":"1"},
      {"requestId":"2","description":"This is a sample","status_id":"1"}
    ]
}
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be wrapping it in Object with a getter called *getRequests*, annother would be to wrap it in a Map:

```
return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, List<Request>>>(Collections.singletonMap("requests", requestList), HttpStatus.OK);
```